# current source pull up

Tags: current-source, pullup

After searching, I was unable to find a clear answer so.....

Looking at datasheets for different microcontrollers and other chipsets, a pull-up or pull-down current is often mentioned instead of a resistance. 
From what I understand, resistors are hard to implement in silicon and/or take up a lot of space, so instead something like a current mirror circuit is used, and the datasheet quotes a pull current.

When modelling this in a circuit simulator, should I insert a current source in place of where the pull up/down resistor would be (between pin and supply or pin and ground), sourcing/sinking current from/to the pin respectively?

In Thevenin/Norton analysis ideal voltage source is considered an ideal short circuit, and ideal current source is considered an ideal open circuit, so if the circuit model has an ideal open circuit where the current source is then how does the voltage at the pin get pulled up to the supply for example, for a source between pin and supply?

Thanks

Comment: *a pull-up or pull-down current is often mentioned instead of a resistance* - citation/reference is needed.

Comment: More often than otherwise a pull-up or pull-down **resistor** is mentioned in data sheets.

Comment: And it will have really wide tolerances.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is based on a speculation without any reference.

Comment: @EugeneSh., here is a reference for you, see Section 9.3, http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/00001979A.pdf, pull up = 58 uA. pull down = 72 uA

Comment: @AliChen section 1 mentions pull-up and pull-down resistors. Just because there is some sub-spec that says the current is this or that, it is a big leap to assume constant current sources are used and section 1 proves this.

Comment: Not sure about microcontrollers, but I have seen some ICs with a current source pull-up, usually on an enable pin or something like that.  To the OP: You have a misconception about the circuit model and Thevanin/Norton analysis.  The circuit model of a current source is NOT an open circuit.

Comment: @Andyaka, you are confusing the USB PHY termination resistors with GPIO pull-ups/downs. The PHY termination requires relatively precise tuning to 45 Ohms USB specifications, and therefore must be implemented differently, usually as a sizable network of smaller passive resistors, configurable/tunable with CMOS switches.

Answer (score 4):

> From what I understand, resistors are hard to implement in silicon
>   and/or take up a lot of space, so instead something like a current
>   mirror circuit is used, and the datasheet quotes a pull current.

Yes, this is correct, in general. Implementation of pull-up resistors is non-trivial using silicon technology. In modern MCU this function is usually configurable, and systematically is implemented as "I/O pad cell" in a universal form. This includes weak switching elements, which behave not exactly as resistors. Implementation of I/O pad cell libraries is highly proprietary and usually not disclosed to public, only in a form of [IBIS models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output_Buffer_Information_Specification), or datasheets in a crude form of either as "effective pull-up current", or as resistor. In fact, the pulls are nonlinear elements, which are difficult to characterize by a single parameter. It is a choice of manufacturer to use whichever parameter suits the particular I/O better.

However, usually the pulls are weak relatively to the main functionality (drive ability) of the I/O cell, so in first approximation they can be modeled as resistors of corresponding ballpark value. Say, the pull-up is said as 58 uA typical. If the input LOW level is, say, 0.8 V, and Vdd is 3.3V, one can use 43 k resistor as a model, (exact definitions are difficult to find, as explained above). This shouldn't change overall logic functionality of a model. But if some design is marginal and sensitive to actual load values, a IBIS model should be used.